# What is the difference between giving input by typing from keyboard and by redirecting?

Tags: keyboard, c, input

I've got a short, easy to understand piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    char buff[0x10];
    read(STDIN_FILENO, buff, 0x10);

    int result = write(STDIN_FILENO, buff, 0x10);
    printf("\n%d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote this tiny program to see the difference between giving input by typing from keyboard versus by redirecting from a file.
When I typed the input `abcdefgh12345678` then hit Enter, the program gave the result:

```
abcdefgh12345678
abcdefgh12345678
16
```

But then I created a file called `input` which contained `abcdefgh12345678` then gave it to our program as input by `./program < input` the result of the program was:

```
-1
```

I debugged and found out the error code was 9, which meant STDIN was busy as it had been being opened for reading to `buff`.

My question is: What can I do, or what is the workaround to give input to the program without having to type from the keyboard so that it won't invoke error when `write()` function is called?

Comment: Why are you writing to stdin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`write(STDIN_FILENO, ...)` will return -1 when `STDIN_FILENO` is not
connected to a terminal, for example when it comes from a pipe as in
`./main < input`.  You can use `isatty(3)` to check if stdin is
connected to a terminal. As a sidenote, it's a good practice to check `write()` return code in the program and let user know that things were wrong by printing a corresponding errno message and write only as many characters as read by `read()`. Your program could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void){
    char buff[0x10];
    size_t count = read(STDIN_FILENO, buff, 0x10); 

    printf("isatty(STDIN_FILENO): %d\n", isatty(STDIN_FILENO));

    int result = write(STDIN_FILENO, buff, count);
    if (result == -1)
      {
         perror("write");
         return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }

    printf("\nresult: %d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
$ ./main
abcdefgh12345678
isatty(STDIN_FILENO): 1
abcdefgh12345678
result: 16
$ ./main  < input
isatty(STDIN_FILENO): 0
write: Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I wrote to STDIN on purpose. This program is just for studying. I wanted to check if writing to STDIN would print to the screen. I'm trying to understand why it works perfectly with the first input method but gave the error with the second.

Comment: @gergeerew: see edited answer